# How do I allow whitespaces in this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I know the question has been asked before, but I can't make it work in my situation.
How do I allow spaces in this regex? (this regex only accepts integers)
Thank you very much

```
 "regex": /^[\-\+]?\d+$/
```

Comment: Whitespaces where? In the middle of the thing or in the beginning or end? If it's the latter, just `trim()` your integer first.

Comment: To you want to accept any arbitrary mix of spaces and digits? examples:  "1", " 2", "3 ", "4 5", " 678  910 1112  ", etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/^[\-\+]?[\d\s]+$/
```

where `\s` represents the **whitespace**

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/^[\-\+]?[\d\s]+$/
```

Use `\s` for whitespace. `\s` allows all whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines). If you only want to allow spaces, then replace `\s` with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
"regex": /^[ +-]?\d+ ?$/
```

Here `[ +-]?` is a character class with space as 1st character that allows optional space before 1 or more digits. This regex also allowed 1 optional space after digits also.

**PS:** You don't need to escape most of the special regex symbols inside character class as shown in my example.